# Change Y axis labels in C3 charts

Tags: jquery, c3

Is it possible to change or categorize the Y axis labels in C3 line chart.[image]

Is it possible to categorize and display the Y axis labels as "Beginner","Intermediate", "Advanced" and "Mastery" where the values would be ranging between 0-25, 25-50, 50-75, 75-100 respectively?

Comment: That doesn't make sense. If you have a line that has points in more than one of the categories, which category should it be labelled as? The green line, for example, seems to have points in Beginner and Mastery, which one would you label it as?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HTML

```
<div id="chart"></div>
```

JS

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        x: 'x',
        columns: [
            ['x', '2013-01-15', '2013-02-15', '2013-03-15', '2013-04-15', '2013-05-15', '2013-06-15'],
            ['Team Alpha', 30, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25],
            ['Team Beta', 30, 100, 14, 20, 15, 50]
        ],
        type: 'spline'
    },    
    tooltip: {
        format: {
            value: function (value, ratio, id) {
                if (value < 25)
                     return 'Beginner';
                else if (value < 50)
                     return 'Intermediate';
                else if (value < 75)
                     return 'Advanced';
                else 
                    return 'Mastery';
            }
        }
    },    
    axis: {
        x: {
            padding: {
                left: 0
            },
            type: 'timeseries',
            tick: {
                format: '%b'
            }
        },
        y: {
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            padding: {
                bottom: 0,
                top: 0
            },
            tick: {
                format: function (d) {
                    switch (d) {
                        case 12.5:
                            return "Beginner"
                        case 37.5:
                            return "Intermediate"
                        case 62.5:
                            return "Advanced"
                        case 87.5:
                            return "Mastery"
                    }
                },
                values: [12.5, 37.5, 62.5, 87.5],
                width: 0
            }
        }
    }
});
```

CSS

```
.c3-axis-y .tick line {
   display: none;
}
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/gqf03ea2/

Comment: This is almost I wanted. But the tooltip doesn't display the value as "Intermediate", etc...
How can I achieve this? @potatopeelings

Comment: Just add the tooltips object as well - have updated my answer and the fiddle link. You might need to change the < to <= e.g.. I wasn't sure if 25 came under Beginner or Intermediate.